# Recursive call and assignment of reference pointers

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, void-pointers

I am feeling confused by the pointers in c++, where I am trying to implement BST.

Instead of (**method 1**)having a type of node, I want to use reference pointer (**method 2**).

1. How could I rewrite if statement, so it would work in a method where pointers been used?
2. How node p in (2) could be assigned to another temp node?

Thank you so much.

```
//1

node* delete(node* p, int k) // deleting k key from p tree
{
  if( k < p->key )
    p->left = remove(p->left,k);
}

//2

void delete(int key, node*& p) {
// recursive call while key is less and assign a new left child.
   if( k < p->key ) {
    //??

    }
}
```

Comment: Method 1 won't work. You may want to return something.

Comment: `delete` is a keyword in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node *getNode(int key, node *haystack){
    if(!haystack)
        return NULL;
    if(haystack->val == key)
        return haystack;
    if(haystack->val < key)
        return getNode(key, haystack->left);
    return getNode(key, haystack->right);
}

void getNode(int key, node *haystack, node *&result){
    if(!haystack){
        result = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if(haystack->val == key){
        result = haystack;
        return;
    }
    if(haystack->val < key){
        return getNode(key, haystack->left, result);
    }
    return getNode(key, haystack->left, result);
}
```

They end up being pretty much the same.  If you actually want to delete, however, there's quite a bit more work involved, since you need to set the deleted node's pointer to the deleted node to `NULL` if the deleted node is a leaf, or you need to add the children of the deleted node to the tree (or delete those, too).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. your method may work, however I cannot assign something, in this case void method. I need to use pointers. Is here any other approach I could take?

Comment: You can just not differentiate haystack and result.  That is, don't have a result argument, and pass in a copy of head as the initial argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to pass a reference so you can zero out the pointer?

something like this should work:

```
void delete_node(int key, node*&p)
{
    if (key < p->key) {
        delete_node(key, p->left);
        delete(p);
        p = nullptr;
    }
}
```

But it's a little naughty. It restricts the number of cases in which your function can be called and it adds some potentially surprising behaviour in that it alters its input argument. It also means that your node's `left` member is being zeroed out un-necessarily when nodes are deleted recursively (since the current node will itself be deleted anyway).